# Why is istream.clear() removing part of my strings while reading doubles and strings?

Tags: c++, cin, istream

I am reading a text file consisting of names and grades with the format:

```
Polly 95 99 95 94 93 98 99 
Abraham 80 85 81 86 95 78 81
```

I use the following code to read each student into a Student_info struct:

```
// read homework grades from an input stream into a vector<double>
istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
{
    if (in)
    {
        // get rid of previous content
        hw.clear();

        // read hw grades
        double grade;
        while (in >> grade) hw.push_back(grade);

        // clear the stream so that input will work for next student
        in.clear();

    }
    return in;
}

istream& read(istream& in, Student_info& s)
{
    // read and store the student's name, midterm, and final
    in >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;
    //std::cout << "The name is " << s.name << std::endl;

    read_hw(in, s.homework);
    return in;
}
```

Later on I print each student's name and overall grade, but something strange happens. Instead of getting

```
Polly 96.6
Abraham 82.2
```

each of the names after the first (Polly) is partially cut off:

```
Polly 96.6
raham 82.2
```

I believe it has something to do with clearing the stream to ready it for the next student:

```
in.clear();
```

It seems to be throwing away the beginning of the next student's name, but I can't just get rid of this line, because the istream needs to return to an OK state.

How can I accomplish this task but make sure I don't throw away part of each student's name? (I am assuming I may NOT know how many homework assignments there are beforehand, so I can't simply read 6 doubles and then move on.)

Comment: Where is your reading loop? Because what you have so far works for me using my reading loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I accomplish this task but make sure I don't throw away part of each student's name?

```
std::string line;
if (getline(in, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    while (iss >> grade)
        hw.push_back(grade);
}
```

This is a more structured approach requiring the numbers be listed on the current line.

Comment: This is an apparent work-around but it doesn't explain why the OP code is performing erroneously.

Comment: @EMiller: true.  The problem's that `in >> grade` is trying to convert e.g. `Abraham` to a `double`, and obviously consumes a couple characters from the stream before giving up and setting an error stream state.  Simply clearing the error state isn't restoring those lost characters.  I don't believe there are any guarantees about the effects of such a failed conversion on the stream.  It's hard for there to be: e.g. gcc 9.2 considers "1E" an error (missing exponent value) rather than a valid double `1`, but by that time it's consumed two characters and some streams only let you restore one.