# Issues reading multiple types from standard input

Tags: c++, cin

I am new to c++ and I am running into issues reading multiple types from standard input. I am trying to take input such as:

```
Smith 93 91 47 90 92 73 100 87
Carpenter 75 90 87 92 93 60 0 98
```

and for each line extract the different fields and store them into a struct and a vector. After running main.cpp the output I get is:

```
Smith
rpenter
```

The full string 'Carpenter' is not being read fully into Student_info.name. It is being cut off as 'rpenter'. Not sure what my issue is here. Could anyone help clear this up?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::istream;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::max;
using std::cin;

struct Student_info {
    std::string name;
    double midterm, final;
    std::vector<double> homework;
};

// read homework grades from an input stream into a vector<double>
istream &read_hw(istream &in, vector<double> &hw) {
    if (in) {
        // get rid of previous contents
        hw.clear();

        // read homework grades
        double x;
        while (in >> x) {
            hw.push_back(x);
        }
        // clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
        in.clear();
    }
    return in;
}

istream &read(istream &is, Student_info &s) {
    // read and store the student's name and midterm and final exam grades
    is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;

    read_hw(is, s.homework); // read and store all the student's homework grades
    return is;
}

int main() {
    vector<Student_info> students;
    Student_info record;
    string::size_type maxlen = 0;

    //read and store all the records, and find the length of the longest name
    while (read(cin, record)) {
        maxlen = max(maxlen, record.name.size());
        students.push_back(record);
    }

    for (vector<Student_info>::size_type i = 0; i != students.size(); ++i) {

        // write the name, padded on the right to maxlen + 1 characters
        cout << students[i].name << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After scanning a while with eyes, I struggled to explain what happens but I couldn't. Hence, I tried to reproduce but I cannot: [**MCVE on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36317188a18c32e6). :-(

Comment: I somehow suspect that `double x; while(in >> x)` consumes `Ca` and cannot push them back to input stream on failure. (I have no better excuse at hand.) Have you tried to test this with a file instead of `std::cin`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce either. Maybe it could be a badly written include of other declaration. You should show the full source file including the declarations (`#include` and `using`). The only (minor) problem here is the `while (read...)` which will try to read twice the end of file.

Comment: @Scheff: works fine even when reading from the console...

Comment: I ended up in [`std::num_get<>::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) and found this: _If the character matches one of "0123456789abcdefxABCDEFX+-"_. Not that `operator>>(std::istream&, double&)` tries to read a hex value. You could try with names not starting with `abcdefABCDEFX` to prove this right or wrong... May be, compiler (and OS) would be helpful. ([Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/)?)

Comment: However, a solution could be to read lines with `std::getline()` at once, and parse them in a `std::istringstream`. The concerning changes would be actually limited to `main()`. (Good work with `std::istream&`.) ;-)

Comment: I edited the above question to include the full source. I am more curious as to why I am experiencing the behavior I am experiencing. This related post is having the same exact problem as I seem to be having (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580400/why-is-istream-clear-removing-part-of-my-strings-while-reading-doubles-and-str?rq=1).

Comment: Also, when running this on ubuntu using the gcc compiler (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4 it is working normally as expected. When I run this through the CLion IDE using the xcode command line tools c++ compiler I experience my above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your while loop inside `read_hw()` function with this:

```
while (in.peek() != '\n' && in >> x) {
    hw.push_back(x);
}
```

But be careful, you must enter every student record in separate line.
Also, the user should input no other character but `'\n'` after the reading the last homework grade for that particular student record.